# No provider for ReloginComponent angular 4

Tags: angular

The error is very straight forward, the issue I am having is get an error saying `No provider for ReloginComponent`

First, this is what I am doing. I am calling a component inside a service via injection.

Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpUtil {

    constructor(private http: Http, private relogin: ReloginComponent) { }

 private catchAuthError (self: HttpUtil) {
        // we have to pass HttpService's own instance here as `self`
        return (res: Response) => {

            if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403 || res.status === 500) {

                //TODO: route the user to the login page again and make a 500 ERROR page
                // if not authenticated
                console.log("ERROR: "+res);

                this.relogin.showDialog();

            }
            return Observable.throw('Not authenticated: '+res);
        };
    }
```

I am trying to have a pop up occur if the user gets an error via:

`this.relogin.showDialog();` in the if statement.

This is my `ReloginModule`

```
@NgModule({
    imports:[
        DialogModule
    ],

    declarations:[
        ReloginComponent
    ],

    exports: [
        ReloginComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        ReloginService
    ]
})
export class ReloginModule {

}
```

I even tried to add it to the ServiceModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports:[
        SmartadminModule,
        ReloginModule
    ],

    exports: [

    ],

    providers:[
        ReloginService
    ]
})
export class ServicesModule{}
```

When that all failed I added it to the `app.module`.

At this point I do not know where it wants me to add it.

Comment: Try private @Inject(ReloginComponent) relogin: ReloginComponent

Comment: Ok the error went away, but no pop up. Looking into it now.

Comment: Added as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add @Inject so that its dependency can be resolved.

So for custom services inside your service Inject its dependency with @Inject

Specific to your code:

```
private @Inject(ReloginComponent) relogin: ReloginComponent
```

You can understand it deeply from this blog. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html